# Create a box with url and lock in webView, IOS

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I want to add at the top of my webView smth like this (ios Safari):
[image]

I know that i can add textField and simple button, but i have no idea how to create a lock which is at the beginning of the URL string. Plaese give me an advice.

Comment: How about: google.com

Comment: @rmaddy it was my first idea, but if web site has no secured access?

Comment: Then don't show the lock.

Comment: is there any analog of https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs in IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week i have figured out! :)
`SFSafariViewController`, the analog of Chrome Custom Tabs in Android, will help you to handle with it.
Example:

```
import SafariServices
```

code for your button:

```
let bookmark = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!
let safari = SFSafariViewController(URL: bookmark)
presentViewController(safari, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to dismiss with animation:

```
func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
let bookmark = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!
let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: bookmark as URL)
present(safari, animated: true, completion: nil) 
//...
func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {
     controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```